# Looker Studio (Data Studio) not filtering empty string

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to filter an empty string in Data Studio's data (Comes from BigQuery).

Basically when running on BigQuery

```sql
SELECT serviceId, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) qty FROM `nyTable` WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN "2022-11-05" AND "2022-11-08"
GROUP BY serviceId
HAVING serviceId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

I get the following

| serviceId | qty |
| --- | --- |
|  | 3323593 |
| 59200 | 309732 |
| ... (Other irrelevant data) | ... |

Adding `AND serviceId != ""` as following correctly removes the empty string row (the first one)

```sql
SELECT serviceId, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) qty FROM `myTable` WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN "2022-11-05" AND "2022-11-08"
GROUP BY serviceId
HAVING serviceId IS NOT NULL AND serviceId != ""
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

But when  i try the same approach on DataStudio it doesn't removes the empty string data

Data Studio's field query i'm trying to use:

```
CASE
  WHEN ( REGEXP_MATCH(ServiceId, R"^\d+$") AND ServiceId != "null" AND ServiceId IS NOT NULL AND ServiceId != "" AND LENGTH(ServiceId) > 3 ) THEN ServiceId
END
```

[image]

In the Data Studio's table it appears like a null value (That's the reason i tried filtering other values)

[image]

My objective with this is to add a parameter (checkbox) to control whether to show invalid values or not. (That's the reason why i'm not using it as a filter)

Any tips?